# is this really O(n) Time Complexity?

Tags: java, string, time-complexity

## Compress a String

```java
public class StrToCompressedStr {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder list=new StringBuilder();
        String str="AAAAABBCDDDEE";

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            list.append(c);
            int count = 0;

            while (i<str.length() && c == str.charAt(i))
            {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            if (count >= 2)
            {
                list.append(count);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);

    }
}
```

I try to compress an String This what i came up with and my Question is, is this really O(n) Linear

Comment: Sure it is.  However, it has a bug.  Have you tried this?  If you're processing As, you bump `i` until you find a `B`.  You then fall through to the `for`, which is going to bump `i` AGAIN, thereby skipping the first `B`.

Comment: Is your concern that there's a loop within a loop?  Because the while loop advances the counter `i` of the `for` loop, it's just advancing the single walk through the characters of `str`, and not performing some additional work on multiple items for each iteration of `i`.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.